# DAX How to get Percentage

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a table visual that looks like this:

```
person_a      false_count     true_count     total
brian         100             200            300
joe           20              30             50
```

I have a table that looks like this (not all values, but this is to help you picture it):

```
person_a  damaged
brian     true
brian     true
brian     false
joe       true
joe       false
```

How can I write a DAX measure to show this:

```
person_a      false_count     false_pct      true_count   true_pct     total
brian         100             25%            300          75%          400
joe           20              40%            30           60%          50
```

I've tried playing around with the CALCULATE function, but this isn't working out for me. I'm just trying to create a DAX measure to get the % so I can add them to the visual.

Answer (score 1):

```
_trueCount =
CALCULATE (
    COUNTA ( 'Table'[damaged] ),
    FILTER ( VALUES ( 'Table'[damaged] ), 'Table'[damaged] = TRUE () )
)
_falseCount =
CALCULATE (
    COUNTA ( 'Table'[damaged] ),
    FILTER ( VALUES ( 'Table'[damaged] ), 'Table'[damaged] = FALSE () )
)
```

From the sample data
[image: Solution]